# Hadoop FileUtil.copy signature

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

In Hadoop 2.2.0 (hadoop-common), I see the following signature and doc for `FileUtil.copy`:

```
 /** Copy files between FileSystems. */
 public static boolean copy(FileSystem srcFS, Path src, 
                            FileSystem dstFS, Path dst, 
                            boolean deleteSource,
                            Configuration conf) throws IOException {
```

What should I make of that `boolean` and simultaneous `IOException`? Is it intended to distinguish between two classes of possible errors, based on a specific understanding of `IOException`?

In the source code, `false` is used `if (!dstFS.mkdirs(dst))` but `IOException` is thrown `if (!dstFS.exists(dst))` (for example).

Is it common practice to both return a status value and throw an exception at the same time? The client code to handle both gets cumbersome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is very old in the history of Apache Hadoop.  The method signature style dates back all the way to at least 2006 when the project split off from Apache Nutch.

https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/9d5bba827967a12bf6182029235df46645eb4264/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.java

(The method name was different, but the signature followed the same style.)

I couldn't find any specific discussion of the method signature style in our development history.  I think a fair theory is that this followed from similar conventions in the JDK `File` API.  The `boolean` return value is relevant to cases when an underlying `mkdirs` or `delete` operation fails.  Similarly, [`java.io.File#delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) and [`java.io.File#mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) use a `boolean` return code to communicate failure.  The Hadoop method most likely followed this style, and then also used `IOException` for additional logic errors and true I/O errors, such as failures to establish a network connection to a remote daemon like the NameNode.

I would not say this style of method signature is common practice or good practice.  As you said, it complicates error handling for client code.  JDK 7 seems to have recognized the weakness of using a `boolean` return code for these operations, because it fails to distinguish the specific reason for failure.  Equivalent methods in the NIO file API that launched in Java 7, such as [`java.nio.file.Files#delete`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) and [`java.nio.file.Files#createDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), chose instead to use specific exception types for error reporting on different cases (and dropped the `boolean` return).  There has been some recent discussion in the Apache Hadoop community about following suit for our own API designs.

The current method signature is unlikely to change, even for the better, for backward compatibility reasons.  We could potentially choose to amend it on a major version boundary according to our [`Compatibility`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Compatibility.html) policy, but it would be challenging.